# Command SystemUpdate in SharePoint Management Shell

Tags: shell, powershell, sharepoint, scheduled-tasks

I created a script in which command is SystemUpdate and it is acting totally different on two locations. Scripts are triggered by Task Scheduler.
My script is:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

$web = Get-SPWeb "https://SiteName"
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]  

foreach ($Item  in $list.Items)  
{      
    $item.SystemUpdate($false);  
}

$web.Dispose()
```

In one location, script is working fine, it doesn't create new item version, but on the other location it changes version, modified and modified by columns/fields.

Locations are on same web application, same site, they are just two different lists.
I also tried row by row manually typed in PowerShell, thought I made a mistake while crating a task in task scheduler, but script acts as creating a new version.

Any suggestion what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do they have different versions of the sharepoint snap-in on each of the machines running the script?